# Как обойти блокировщик рекламы и отключенные куки в браузере

Tags: javascript, cookie

Сделал баннер на сайт, по клику по кнопке закрыть, в куки записывается инфа, эта инфа живет час и уничтожается. Добавил условие, если инфа в куках есть то баннер не всплывает. То-есть баннер всплывает раз в час. Столкнулся с проблемой, если есть блокировщик рекламы или куки в браузере запрещены, баннер всплывает постоянно... Есть ли решения обойти блокировщики?

Comment: Написать жалостливый текст для пользователя, в котором попросить его включить куки. Другого пути нет.

Comment: Ну или используйте localStorage или sessionStorage.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать с localStorage.